# Why ”false -a true“ and "true -a false" in shell return a different results?

Tags: bash, shell

IMO, `-a` and `&&` are all `and` operation in shell, so I assume `true -a false` and `false -a true` would both return "false". Well the fact is

```bash
[root@master ~] true -a false
[root@master ~] echo $?
0
[root@master ~] false -a true
[root@master ~] echo $?
1
```

```bash
[root@master ~] a=[ true -a false ]
[root@master ~] echo $a
true
[root@master ~] a=[ false -a true ]
[root@master ~] echo $a
true
```

Why did this happen, and what should I do if I want to operate `and` in Shell?

Comment: That is funny. I like your examples.

Comment: Bash does not support Boolean values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's the general syntax of a command in shell is:

```
[var=val...] cmd [args...]
```

The `var=val` are exporting environment variable `var` with the value `val` for the duration of command `cmd`.

> Why did this happen

Both commands `true` and `false` ignore arguments. `true anything` exits with 0 exit status, `false anything` exits with non-zero exit status. `true -a false` executes command `true` with two arguments, sting `-a` and string `false`. `true` ignores arguments, exits with zero exit status. The same for `false`.

`a=[` exports a variable `a` with the value of string `[` to the environment of the next command.

```
$ a=[ env | grep '^a='
a=[
```

`a=[ true -a false ]` set's environment variable `a` to the value of string `[` and then executes command `true` with 3 arguments string `-a`, the string `false` and the string `]`.

```
  a=[ true -a false ]
  |   |    |  |     \----  third argument
  |   |    |  \----------  second argument
  |   |    \-------------  first argument
  |   \------------------  command to execute
  \----------------------  var=val, exports a variable
```

`true` ignores the arguments and `true` once again, exits with exit status `0`. The same is for `false`, with non-zero exit status.

The value `echo $a` that shows `true` is the value that you previously have set in your shell. The `a=[ true ...` only set's the variable `a` for the duraction of the command, after that the variable has it's own value.

```
$ a=anything_here
$ a=anything_here2 true anything_here3
$ echo $?
0               # true exits with 0 exit status
$ echo $a
anything_here   # the variable `a` preserved its value set before the command
```

> Why ”false -a true“ and "true -a false" in shell return a different results?

Because commands `false` and `true` exit with different exit status.

Note: the strings `true` `false` `[` `]` `-a` have no special meaning for shell. These are all strings. The string `-a` and `]` have special meaning when passed as an argument for the *command* `[`. It's still the string `-a`, but when the executable `[` is executed, it parses the arguments and acts specially on the string `-a`. There happen to be executables named `true` and `false`. The strings `[`, `]`, `true`, `false` or `-a` by itself have no significant for shell, these are all just strings.

> -a and && are all and operation in shell,

No, `-a` is the string `-a` in shell. `&&` is an "and" operation in shell. `-a` is the "and" operator for `[` or `test` *commands*. Note: because of problems with `[`, prefer to use `[ ... ] && [ ... ]` instead of `[ ... -a ... ]`.

References: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/test.html , https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion , https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/true.html , https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/false.html , https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_01 .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for KamilCuk's answer.
After reading that ,here's my shorter version.

`true -a false` and `false -a true` is just a command  who contains two arguments( -a [false/true]). Its exit code depend on the command itself which return 0 and 1 respectively.

`a=[ true -a false` is the same but variable `a` is being set to`'['` before execute `true -a false`.

`a` shall be unset if not `set -a` or it's will be `'['`